# Mongodb lookup for array of ids with nested array of objects in other collection

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongo db i am trying to find a lookup for two collection

one collection is users which has tags like

```js
{
  _id: "fdkjkjs",
  first_name: "",
  last_name: "",
  role: "admin",
  tags:
    [
      { _id: "tag_1_id", name: "Tag 1" },
      { _id: "tag_2_id", name: "Tag 2" },
      { _id: "tag_3_id", name: "Tag 3" },
      { _id: "tag_4_id", name: "Tag 4" }
    ]
}
```

and a post collection is as below

```js
{
  _id: "fdkjkjs",
  title: "",
  slug: "",
  tags: ["tag_1_id", tag_3_id]
}
```

So I want to get all the tags in post list API with the names that are in users collection.

so result i wanted belike

```js
[{
  _id: "fdkjkjs",
  title: "",
  slug: "",
  tags: ["tag_1_id", tag_3_id],
  selectedTags: [
    { _id: "tag_1_id", name: "Tag 1" },
    { _id: "tag_3_id", name: "Tag 3" }
  ],
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

```
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "tags",
      "foreignField": "tags._id",
      "as": "selectedTags"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "selectedTags": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": { "$first": "$selectedTags.tags" },
          "as": "item",
          "cond": { $in: [ "$$item._id", "$tags" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3x4DXXkIuzC)

---

**Method 2**

```
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: { tags_post: "$tags" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$unwind": "$tags"
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [ "$tags._id", "$$tags_post" ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$replaceWith": "$tags"
        }
      ],
      as: "selectedTags"
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gpv3u2SAIre)

---

**Method 3**

```
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "tags",
      foreignField: "tags._id",
      let: { tags_post: "$tags" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$unwind": "$tags"
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [ "$tags._id", "$$tags_post" ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$replaceWith": "$tags"
        }
      ],
      as: "selectedTags"
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/seMiML1EvUl)

Method 2 arrange data first and then lookup, while method 3 lookup first and then arrange data. Though 2 and 3 looks similar, I think method 3 is faster than method 2.

Comment: Note for future visitors (as I was), the "tags" inside the pipeline (as in method 2 and method 3) refers to the foreign document.
So if your property names are slightly different, account for that